# How to make PyCharm always show line numbers

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I cannot seem to be able to find the setting to enable line numbers for *all* files, but I have to always right click and enable this on per file basis.

There must be a global setting for this, right?

Comment: Ugh, why would they make them disabled by default? It's like that in Xcode and Vim too.

Answer (score 354, accepted):

Version 2.6 and above:
PyCharm (far left menu) -> Preferences... -> Editor (bottom left section) -> General -> Appearance -> Show line numbers checkbox

[image]

Version 2.5 and below:
Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Show line numbers checkbox

Comment: PyCharm also has search bar at the left top corner of the Settings dialog, very useful.

Comment: How did you miss it?  Categorized as Appearance??!  This is a must-have for most programmers and it's hidden where one would expect to find color schemes and such...

Comment: I miss it too ¬¬ ... what i see is View->Active editor->Line numbers, but that is only for current document :D and tried on the options but didn't focus into Appearance item.

Answer (score 67):

**For version 4.0, 4.5** on Windows

*File -> Settings*

Then,

*Editor -> General -> Appearance -> Show line numbers*

**For version 4.0** on Mac OSX

PyCharm-->Preferences

Then,

Editor-->General-->Appearance-->checkbox: "Show line numbers"

Comment: On Mac OSX Ver. 4.0 it was: PyCharm-->Preferences-->Editor-->General-->Appearance-->checkbox: "Show line numbers"

Comment: It shows them. But then when I click in the editing window they disappear. So ......

Answer (score 37):

For version 3.0 (Community Edition):

File -> Settings -> Editor (under IDE Settings) -> Appearance -> check 'Show line numbers'

Answer (score 25):

PyCharm Version 3.4.1(***For all files in the project***):

> File -> Preferences -> Editor (IDE Settings) -> Appearance -> mark
>   'Show line numbers'

PyCharm Version 3.4.1(***only for existing file in the project***):

> View -> Active Editor -> Show Line Numbers

[image]

Comment: The original question was about how to enable it globally (i.e. for all newly opened files).  The menu item you have highlighted only enables line numbers for the currently open file.

Comment: yes u are right, I have just realized that; but it might be helpful. Thanks for your warning.

Answer (score 16):

For version 2.6 and up, the dialog is in the "Preferences" dialog, access using Cmd ',':

PyCharm (far left menu) -> Preferences... -> Editor (bottom left section) -> Appearance -> Show line numbers checkbox

Comment: Not displaying the 'Show line numbers' option. Pycharm version 2019.1.2

Answer (score 3):

v. community 5.0.4 (linux): 
File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance -> now check 'Show line numbers', confirm w. OK an voila :)

Answer (score 2):

**Using Search bar**

1. Press 2 times `Shift`
2. Paste `/editor /appearance/`  and then
3. Click on `Show line numbers` toggle button

---

**For Windows and Linux**

> ```
> File | Settings | Editor | General | Appearance
> ```

**For macOS**

> ```
> IntelliJ IDEA | Preferences | Editor | General | Appearance
> ```

---

**Using shortcut**

> ```
> Ctrl+Alt+S
> ```

Then

***Editor > General > Appearance***

Click on Show line numbers toggle button.

---

[Pycharm Official Doc (Appearance)](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/settings-editor-appearance.html)