# how to make pycharm always show line numbers in ubuntu

Tags: python, ubuntu, pycharm

I know how to do it in the windows version but on ubuntu i dont have a 'show lines numbers' chekbox in settings/appearance

thanks

Comment: This is not the right place for your question. Try http://superuser.com/

Comment: @InbarRose. it's the right place, see the FAQ: **software tools commonly used by programmers**.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You are looking in the wrong place, it's under `Settings` | **Editor** | `Appearance`, see the [related answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8086109/104891).

[image: Show line numbers]

Answer (score 3):

I just spent 5 minutes looking for it myself.  For PyCharm 4.x, that setting can be found under **Settings** -> **Editor** -> **General** -> **Appearance**.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Updating the answer (Apr 2016)

> PyCharm Community Edition 2016.1.2
>
> Build #PC-145.844, built on April 8, 2016
>
> JRE: 1.8.0_60-b27 x86
>
> JVM: Java HotSpot(TM) Server VM by Oracle Corporation

Windows version, but I guess in Ubuntu will be the same.

**View** > **Active Editor** > **Show Line Numbers**

[image]

---

EDIT: [Duplicated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10187228/how-to-make-pycharm-always-show-line-numbers)